# Jmonkey loading texture from fails

Tags: java, textures, image, assets, jmonkeyengine

I have the following basic code:

```
public void simpleInitApp() {
    Box b = new Box(1, 1, 1);
    Geometry geom = new Geometry("Box", b);
    Texture cube1Tex = assetManager.loadTexture(
    "/home/glados/codes/3/assets/Textures/map/oldParchment.jpg");

    Material mat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
    mat.setTexture("ColorMap", cube1Tex);
    geom.setMaterial(mat);

    rootNode.attachChild(geom);
}
```

which is supposed to simply attach a texture to the cube loaded from Textures/map/oldParchment.jpg

My resource setup is as following: [image]

running this gives the following error:

```
com.jme3.asset.AssetNotFoundException: /home/glados/codes/3/assets/Textures/map/oldParchment.jpg (Flipped) (Mipmapped)
    at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadAsset(DesktopAssetManager.java:283)
    at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadTexture(DesktopAssetManager.java:346)
    at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadTexture(DesktopAssetManager.java:356)
    at mygame.Main.simpleInitApp(Main.java:27)
    at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.initialize(SimpleApplication.java:226)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:130)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you are giving assetManager should start from the assets folder of your project.

So the path should just be:

"Textures/map/oldParchment.jpg"

This is the same for all assets loaded with assetManager.

Compare your code to the tutorial for [loading assets](http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:beginner:hello_asset).